# Testing data generator for Intersystems Caché?

Tags: intersystems-cache, data-generation, faker

Are there any easy ways (i.e. libraries) to create testing data for Caché, similar to the Populator and Faker gems for Ruby/Rails?

** edit **
I am trying to create test data for an [Epic](http://www.epic.com) implementation.  In addition to the electronic-medical-record (EMR) application, the implementation includes a tool called 'Text'.  I'm hoping that I can use the data-generator with Text.

Comment: Curious what you found out trying %Populate in Epic..  have any update?

Answer (score 4):

The %Populate class has a bunch of methods designed to help you create test data for your persistent classes.

```
Do ##class(MyApp.MyClass).Populate()
```

Could also use %PopulateUtils class directly to get random data returns directly.

```
USER>w ##class(%PopulateUtils).Name()
Taylor,Kenny O.
```

.

```
USER>w ##class(%PopulateUtils).Street()
3012 Oak Drive
```

.

```
USER>w ##class(%PopulateUtils).SSN()
113-89-3577
```

Comment: +1 for answer.  I'm hoping that Populate will work with Text (see question).

Comment: I'm also an Epic person, but am not familiar with Text. If you can write a routine with object script in Text.. I wouldn't see why this wouldn't work.  I would look at the %PopulateUtils class.  Not sure how to implement this in Text, but %PopulateUtils generates individual random test data directly through it's methods.  See my edits above.

Answer (score 1):

mccrackend is right. The docs on this can be found here:

http://docs.intersystems.com/cache20102/csp/docbook/DocBook.UI.Page.cls?KEY=GOBJ_populate